# PAT tokens for service accounts for service connections

Tags: azure-devops

In our DevOps projects we are using various Service Connections, which only support PAT authentication e.g. Azure Repos , SonarCloud, etc. For those, we currently provide PAT tokens generated by a specific DevOps user, usually Project Administrator.

We would like to switch to service accounts instead of regular users. To do that we configured Service Principals in Entra and added them to specific DevOps projects.

Then we tried to create PAT using the API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=powershell):

```
az login --service-principal -u *** -p *** --tenant ***
$result = az account get-access-token --scope '499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default' | ConvertFrom-Json

$auth = "Bearer $($result.accessToken)"
$azureDevOpsApiVersion = "7.1-preview"
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = $auth
}

Invoke-RestMethod -H $headers "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/***/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=$azureDevOpsApiVersion"
```

This returns "Service principals are not allowed to perform this action." I found in the docs that you cannot generate PATs for service principals indeed.

**Main Question:** If Service Principals cannot generate PATs, how can we use service accounts in service connections that only support PAT?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps, it is not possible to generate PAT for Service Principal as it is not a general sign-in user of the Azure DevOps. You need to generate the AAD Access Token for Service Principal.

Follow the steps below to generate the AAD Access Token for Service Principal to access resources in Azure DevOps:

##### Prerequisites on Azure Portal:

1. Go to **Microsoft Entra ID** (known as previous **Azure Active Directory**) > **App registrations**, create a Service Principal if you do not have one in the AAD.
2. Open the Service Principal, go to **Certificates & secrets** > **Client secrets** tab, create a client secret for the Service Principal if there is not an existing valid client secret. Copy and remember the value of the client secret.

##### Prerequisites in Azure DevOps:

1. Go to **Organization Settings** > **Azure Active Directory**, ensure the organization has connected to the AAD which the Service Principal is in.
2. Go to **Organization Settings** > **Users**, search and add the Service Principal into the organization.
3. After successfully adding the Service Principal into the organization, add it into a security group so that you can manage the permissions of the Service Principal through that group in the organization.
4. For example, if you want to use the Service Principal to clone Azure Git Repos from a project. Go to **Project Settings** > **Repositories** > **Security**. Search and select the group which the Service Principal is in. Ensure you have at least set the **`Read`** permission to **`Allow`** for the group.

##### Generate the AAD Token for the Service Principal:

Using Bash script to generate the token.

```bash
access_token=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
-d 'client_id={client_id}&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials' | jq -r '.access_token')

echo $access_token
```

- Replace **`{tenant_ID}`** with the **Directory (tenant) ID** of AAD.
- Replace **`{client_id}`** with the **Application (client) ID** of the Service Principal.
- Replace **`{client_secret}`** with the value of the client secret created in the Service Principal.

##### Note:

The AAD Token has an only 24-hour lifetime as AAD will regularly rotate the token. So, you need to refresh the token at least once every 24 hours.

Comment: this seems pretty much the same as I already did. I cannot use those AAD/Entra tokens in DevOps service connections that require PAT

Comment: @filip, Check whether there are any CAP (Conditional Access policies) rules set in your AAD (Microsoft Entra ID) that may restrict the access. If so, contact the AAD admin to adjust the CAP rules to allow the access.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops we can generate PAT for SA . I think OP followed same procedure but he got error. can you pls clarify what i'm missing.

Comment: @santosh.a, Actually, the token mentioned in that docs is the AAD access token for the service principal managed in the AAD. It is different than the PAT generated in Azure DevOps for general sign-in user.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. can you suggest what can be done if I want to use generic PAT to create devops agent pools instead of individual tokens. im planning to installl agent pool on aks and use auto scale using keda. I want to avoid using individual tokens

Comment: @santosh.a, Now, Azure DevOps has supported using a Service Principal to register agents. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-227-update#pipeline-agents-can-be-registered-using-microsoft-entra-id-instead-of-a-pat).